# Setting type of templated code at each execution

Tags: c++, templates

I have some code that uses templates so I can switch between float, real, double, for computation precision or memory savings.
Now I'd like to let the user choose the precision at each execution but I'm not sure how I should.

Let's say in my main.cpp I have

```
// main.cpp
Object<double> obj;
obj.doSomething();
```

Is there a way to "set" the type used ? Something like the following ?

```
//main.cpp

std::cout << "Choose Precision ": << std::endl;
std::cin  >> PRECISION; // eg float or double

? fix precision and use generic code below with it ?

Object<PRECISION> obj; 

obj.doSomething();
```

**UPDATE**

It's now clear I can't at execution time. Thanks.

Could I still use generic templated code in the main so that I only have 1 line to edit to compile the code at different precisions ?

Update answered by Kevin Cadieux: `typedef double MyPrecision;`

Comment: Template instantiation appears at compile time, use dynamic polymorphism for runtime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't set the type of a template at runtime, but you can select which template specialization to use. For example:

```
template <typename T>
void doStuff<T>()
{
  Object<T> obj;
  // do something with obj
}

int main()
{
  // same PRECISION getting code
  switch (PRECISION) {
  case (x) :
    doStuff<double>();
    break;
  case(y) :
    doStuff<float>();
    break;
  ....
}
```

Comment: Oh I misunderstood your answer at first. Turns out it's exactly what I need, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

No because templates work at *compile time*, you are trying to change types at *run time*. If you want to do this you should use inheritence and polymorphism.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put: no. Template instantiations occur at compile time. Your PRECISION variable will only be known at runtime so you cannot use it to instantiate a template.

As John said, in cases like this (and any other cases where behavior is known only based on runtime conditions), it would be most fitting to use polymorphism.

You could perhaps have a class hierarchy similar to this:

```
class SomePrecisionBase
{
    virtual double compute() = 0;  //Or whatever
};

class MySuperPreciseClass
{
    virtual double compute(); //Super precise computation
};

class MyNotSoPreciseClass
{
    virtual double compute(); //Not so precise computation
};
```

Then, in order to build the correct class using the user input from `std::cin`, you will probably want to write a factory function like so:

```
SomePrecisionBase* factory(int precision)
{
    //Construct a concrete class here and return it as a SomePrecisionBase pointer
    //Also consider using an std::shared_ptr instead of a raw pointer
}
```

**EDIT**

But this is definitely weird if you just want to choose between double and single floating-point computation. I would prefer juanchopanza's approach in that case.

Alternatively, you could have a typedef somewhere in your code that goes something like:

```
typedef double MyPrecision;
```

If you want to bring the decision to compile time, then you could instantiate your templates with MyPrecision and only have one place to modify if you change your mind.

Comment: I have many templated classes, all using typename T for precision, but definitely something to think about, thanks.

Comment: @user2287453 If you absolutely want to defer decision to runtime, then I would go for what juanchopanza has said. Otherwise you can use a typedef like shown in my edit but then it needs to be known at compile time.